# How can Chef detect an AWS ec2 instance type?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, ohai-gem

I need to have an arbitrary script ran if an instance is run on an ENA enabled ami (eg, c5.2xlarge) A shell command easily enough validates the type:

```
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_name
c5.2xlarge
```

...but I'm guessing there is something in ohai that will help with this detection as well. Not sure where / how to access the attribute however. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the EC2 metadata gathered by ohai, try `node['ec2']['instance-type']` or something like that (might be `instance_type`, run `ohai ec2` from a command line to see what data it grabs).

Comment: Thanks that got me exactly what I needed.